lightgallery no me coge las variables ruta(php) en el data-src
bueno digamos que tras muchos años sin tocar este mundillo , me estoy  actualizando y volviendo aponer al dia ... el tema es que estoy creando una aplicacion en la que combino slick-slide y lightgallery , la funcion recorre un directorio en busca de imagenes, si las encuentra, slick-slide me genera un carousel de miniaturas. He implementado en el html para que cuando le de a una imagen Lightgallery me la abra a pantalla completa y si quiero desplazarme por las imagenes a pantalla completa, poder hacerlo... como son muchas imagenes , cada vez que php en cuentra una imagen me genera el codigo para introducirlo, y me lo introduce , da igual que sea 1 imagen , como 100 el problema me erradica en lightgallery, que se abre pero no localiza , ni el selector, ni el data-src, que por lo visto debe de usar.... alguien seria capaz de iluminarme y decirme en que estoy fallando, que estoy haciendo mal....
`
function generarSlickSlide($nombre) {
    $primera_letra = strtolower($nombre[0]);
    $ruta_base = "../../Public/img/$primera_letra/$nombre/";
    $ruta_thumbs = $ruta_base . "Thumbs/";

    // Verificar si la carpeta Thumbs existe
    if (!is_dir($ruta_thumbs)) {
        return ['html' => '', 'data' => []]; // Si no existe, retornar una cadena vacía y un array vacío
    }
    // Obtener todas las imágenes en la carpeta Thumbs
    $imagenes = glob($ruta_thumbs . "*.jpg");
    $count = count($imagenes); // Contar el número de imágenes

    // Generar el HTML para cada imagen
    $html = '';
    $data = [];
    foreach ($imagenes as $index => $imagen) {
        $nombre_imagen = basename($imagen);
        $activeClass = ($index < 10) ? 'slick-active' : '';
        $html .= '
        <div class="slick-slide ' . $activeClass . '" data-slick-index="' . $index . '" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 156px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide' . str_pad($index, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
            <a id="" href="' . $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen . '" data-track="OPEN" data-track-action="PHOTOS"
               data-src="' . $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen . '" thumb="' . $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen . '" rel="nofollow" class="item" tabindex="0">
                <img src="' . $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen . '" alt="' . htmlspecialchars($nombre) . '" width="123" height="185">
                <noscript>
                    <img src="' . $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen . '" alt="' . htmlspecialchars($nombre) . ' Thumb-" width="123" height="185" />
                </noscript>
            </a>
        </div>';
        $data[] = [
            'src' => $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen,
            'thumb' => $ruta_thumbs . $nombre_imagen,
            'subHtml' => '<h4>' . htmlspecialchars($nombre) . '</h4>'
        ];
    }

    return ['html' => $html, 'data' => $data, 'count' => $count];
}

` agradeceria cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.....
